# How to set up my Gnuplot for plotting

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I was using gnuplot to plot and draw graphs before with my school laptop. Now I start using another PC which also has gnuplot software.

But when I command >gnuplot, it shows

```
terminal type set to "unknown"
```

and I cannot plot. It does not show any error but just no graph appears.

How can I set my gnuplot so that I can plot again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to set a valid terminal.  I'm not sure what causes it to be set to "unknown".

Typing `set terminal` will give you a list of all terminals.  Pick the one that you want to use and type `set terminal terminal_name` where **terminal_name** is the name of the terminal that you want.

For instance, on Windows, I use the *wxt* terminal; to set it to this one, you would type `set terminal wxt`.

Comment: Or set terminal x11 for linux.

Comment: thanks a lot. Now, I have set my terminal to x11 as your advise. And seems it works. The terminal runs and generate sequences of numbers as if it is creating a graph., such as  poly('red',2,[
 683.0,310.0,701.0,310.0],0,2,1,7754,0,0,0,0,8,3,0,[
])
],
7756,0,[
]).
group([,,,, but no graph is generated. Do you know why it is happening in that way? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure what would cause it to create output like that, unless the terminal is corrupted in some way.  Try some of the other terminals and see if one of them works.

Comment: Thanks, now i command this "sudo apt-get install gnuplot-x11", install from the start and now it works. thanks :)